# How can I have the names of the authors of my followed books?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In user.rb (models) I have this :
has_many :followed, class_name: Following
has_many :followed_books, through: :followed, source: :book

In followed.rb, I have the books' id and the users' id.
In book.rb, I have also the author (with the author's name)

How can I have the names of the authors of my followed books ?

Is this correct: current_user.followed_books(:author) 
or just current_user.followed_books.author ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if 'author' is an attribute that represents the name of the author you can just access the names like this:

```
current_user.followed_books.pluck(:author)
```

if 'author' is an object:

```
current_user.followed_books.includes(:author).pluck("authors.name")
```

if you want the ids

```
current_user.followed_books.includes(:author).pluck("authors.id")
```

Comment: if I want the ids can I write: current_user.followed_books.pluck(:author).id ?

Comment: i edited my answer in case 'author' is an object, and the table in your db called 'authors'

Comment: oh ! You're very skilled ! Author is string. last question, please :)
And if I want all the books of that author ?
current_user.followed_books.includes(:author).pluck("authors.book") ?

Comment: if 'author' is a string , you can just filter books by author `Book.where(author: "author_name")`

Comment: in that case `current_user.followed_books.where(author: "author_name")`